# Python：nest list assignment does not work properly

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

Thr version of Python is 2.6.6

```
n = 0
list1=["","",""]
list2=[]
for ...    :
    # a b c changes every loop
    list1[0]=a
    list1[1]=b
    list1[2]=c
    list2[n].append(list1)
    n += 1

for j in range(n):
    print list2[j]
```

The problem is that every item in list2 is the value of the last loop, Why?
It seems caused by shallow copy, but i don't kown how to fix it.

Comment: Does `list2[n].append([a, b, c])` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append a *copy* of `list1`:

```
list2.append(list1[:])
```

Otherwise, what gets appended is a reference to the same single list.